# How to link URLs with parentheses correctly?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Linking a URL with ) in it doesn't work as that's the same character that ends the link tag.
I tried some basic escaping, unsuccessfully.

Is there a solution to this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12729/how-to-link-urls-with-parentheses-correctly?/) by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been having trouble with that, too.

Turns out you can escape '(' with "%28" and ')' with "%29", the ASCII hex values. The close parenthesis is all that's really required, but the other helps to make things look less "unbalanced".

EDIT:

Even with that escape, it can be tricky. Sometimes the link works while editing, yet fails after the edit is committed.

We should probably open a ticket on this behavior.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1